# Which version of Python is installed in the OSGeo4W shell?

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w

Does anyone know how I can find out which version of Python ships with each version of QGIS?

Specifically I'd like to know when the OSGeo4W shell changed from Python 3.7 to Python 3.9.

I think all of our users have upgraded QGIS recently and are all on Python 3.9, but I'd like to be able to tell them "you need to be on at least version 3.x for our plugins to work".

I can't find this information in the doc or the changelog - there are a few mentions of Python, but nothing about specific versions.

---

I'm struggling to make myself understood so I'll ask a different question: if you're reading this, please comment below with your QGIS version and Python version (see answers for how to find this if you don't know).

I'll start: QGIS 3.22.16 and Python 3.9.5

Comment: I have theese 3: QGIS 3.30.0 Python-Version 3.9.5
QGIS 3.28.4 Python-Version 3.9.5
QGIS 3.26.3 Python-Version 3.9.5

Comment: I suppose it is possible to build QGIS against a desired Python version https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/52050. Therefore it is not possible to say that QGIS version 3.x.y is always built against Python 3.y.x. However, maybe OSGeo4W build environment is somehow documented. Unfortunately I do not know where it is.

Comment: This question only makes sense in the context of the monolithic Windows installer, where a specific python version is packaged with a specific QGIS version, however I have reason to suspect that the installers might get repackaged and overwritten as I have encountered an old install of 3.16.16 using python 3.7, whereas the freshly downloaded 3.16.16 installer from the [archive](https://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/) installs python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

Open an OSGEO4W command shell and type `python --version` or you can check in the installer which will show you the version that is currently and about to be installed.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I know how to find the Python version on the QGIS I have installed on my machine. What I want to know if if I tell a user to install QGIS 3.x they will have Python 3.9 in their shell. What is x?

Answer (score 1):

or other way from within the python console:

```
import sys
print('{}.{}'.format(sys.version_info.major,sys.version_info.minor))
```

Comment: If you read the question, you'll see I'm not asking about my specific version of Python. I want to know what version of QGIS I need to tell users to install.

Comment: what about QGIS Menu->Help->About, this tells you the installed Python version.

Comment: But I'm not talking about one installation of QGIS on one machine. I have a room full of analysts - what version do they need to install?